# perl facebook login cookies error

Tags: facebook, perl, cookies, authentication

so i just wrote perl script to login facebook and crawl some data from there but when the server response comes with an error that my browser does not allow cookies to be stored, i used cookie jar so far and i had this problem only with facebook, here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP 5.64;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$browser->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0');
$browser->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new('file' => './cookies.lwp', 'autosave' => 1, ignore_discard => 1));
$browser->default_header('Referer' => "http://facebook.com/");
my $email = "email";
my $pass = "pass";

my $login = $browser->post("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1", {"email" => "$email", "pass" => "$pass", "locale" => "en_US" ,"default_persistent" => 0})->content;
open (MYFILE, ">fbresponse.html");
print MYFILE "$login";
close (MYFILE);

system("START fbresponse.html");
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I do not know why this happens, but in the past, it has helped me to instead use IE6 as browser agent, some sites respond differently then. Cookie jar has worked fine for me when I had to use it.

Comment: @bytepusher it has nothing to do with the user agent, it can't set the cookie at the first place i think it has something to do with JS but im waiting for comments..

Comment: that would have been my bet, take a look at WWW::Mechanize::Firefox if you need javascript, I have used that before with some success.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that what you are trying to do is not allowed. You should not scrape Facebook using anything other than the Graph API and access token. You can read more on that in the [Automated Data Collection Terms](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php).